# Cannot find System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper.GenerateUrl in .Net Core 3.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

I'm trying to port a asp.net mvc 3.0 to Asp.Net Core 3.0 but now I'm stuck and Cannot find `UrlHelper.GenerateUrl` in .Net Core 3.0. even the `UrlHelper` in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing` doesn't have `GenerateUrl`, seems like it is removed in .Net Core version 3.0. are there any replacements?

Comment: Source code shows that they are now protected https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Routing/UrlHelper.cs

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [LinkGenerator](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.routing.linkgenerator). From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing):

> URL generation is based on addresses, which support arbitrary
>   extensibility:
>
> The Link Generator API (LinkGenerator) can be resolved anywhere using dependency injection (DI) to generate URLs.
>
> Where the Link Generator API isn't available via DI, IUrlHelper offers methods to build URLs.

DI example:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private readonly LinkGenerator _linkGenerator;

    public MyController(LinkGenerator linkGenerator)
    {
        _linkGenerator = linkGenerator;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var url = _linkGenerator.GetPathByAction(nameof(Index), "My", new { someParameter });

        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: it is almost similar but does'nt take the RouteValueDictionary as argument, which allows to set multiple Route parameters through the dictionary including Action Name and controller name. for example in the old framework we could use: 
`UrlHelper.GenerateUrl(null, null, null, routes, RouteTable.Routes, htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext, true);`

Comment: I assume you can use [VirtualPathContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing#url-generation-reference) for that.